# Creating a lookup list table from a query, and it's located on a form page, I'm requesting a $_GET variable

Tags: php, sql

Here's my query:

```
$near = ('select id, 
first, 
last, 
trainer_address1, 
CITY, 
STATE, 
trainer_zip 
from event.A.trainer where trainer zip ='.($_GET['zip1']));
echo lookup_gen::query_results_table($near, matry::here_to('edit'));

echo "<pre>"; print_r ($near); echo "</pre>";
```

When I print_r I get everything empty except the `$_GET` variable for zip1.
like so:

```
select id, 
first, 
last, 
trainer_address1, 
CITY, 
STATE, 
trainer_zip 
from event.A.trainer where trainer zip =92054
```

If i drop the $_GET variable and hardcode a zip code it works fine:

```
$near = ("select id, 
first, 
last, 
trainer_zip 
from event.A.trainer where trainer_zip = '66415'");
echo lookup_gen::query_results_table($near, matry::here_to('edit'));
```

Am i using the $_GET variable wrong? Additionally, if anyone is interested in looking at lookup_gen::query_results_table i'll post the code for that function.

I hope that makes sense and i surely hope someone can help me. Thank you.

---

This worked for me:

```
$near = ("select id, 
first, 
last, 
trainer_zip 
from event.A.trainer where trainer_zip ='".($_GET['zip1']."'"));
echo lookup_gen::query_results_table($near, matry::here_to('edit'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to surround the variable with single quotes so it should be

```
    $zip = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['zip1']);

    $near = "select id, first, last, trainer_address1, CITY, STATE, trainer_zip "
        "from event.ACS.trainer where trainer zip ='{$zip}'";
```

Comment: another option is to use curly braces, like: {$_GET['zip1']} , in case too much quotes can confuse you.

Comment: and as alway make sure you are sanitizing any data coming in from userland prior to sending it to your database

Comment: I'll give the curly braces a go too just to get use to that syntax as well. Also, this data is not live nor will it ever be live on the internet. I will sanitize for my own sanity sake. Thank you everyone.

Comment: Can you explain the $zip variable? I'll mark the answer as correct as soon as it allows me. What's going on up there?

Comment: edited it ... it was a placeholder left in a suggested edit... i meant the db escaping function for the database that your using. I was assuming you are using mysql

Comment: i'm using sql server 2008. Also, I might of changed something up a bit different than you had it, i don't understand the quotes in yours after zip and before from event, a bit confusing with all those quotes but i got it to work. I edited my above post with what exactly is working for me.

Comment: that function will guard you against sql injection attacks ... imagine someone passed `'; delete from table event.ACS.trainer;` as the value zip1